# React native simple firebase push notification isn't working, causing Pod failure or build fail even pod install successful with modular_headers=>true

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]React native simple firebase push notification isn't working, causing Pod failure or build fail even pod install successful with **modular_headers=>true** , somehow I manage to run the build with downgrading firebase package but that cause appinitialize faliure or an error says : **Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp().** I have tried all possible solutions but I don't know what cause the issue on IOS. here is an image when I install pods and with **modular_headers=>true** it causes build failure. Packages that I have installed are:"@react-native-firebase/app": "^15.2.0" and
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^15.2.0"
**Updated** Somehow I manage to install pods by adding **pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true** in my pod files and Build completed successfully, now the issue remains is when I build project causes the issue on Code side which is **ERROR  Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()**

Any Help will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: can you please add your detail error

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: ok I will provide more details in the form of screenshot or error statement? Because yet I just installed firebase Libraries that causes failure on pod side.

Comment: I've edited my question with pod error screenshot.